# iOS application .ipa file crashing only in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, crash-reports

I am getting a strange error. My application runs nicely in XCODE simulator without any error in both iPad and iPhone. However when I archive the project and install and run the .ipa file in iPad it crashes. But it does not crash in iPhone. I am using ZXing library and it crashes whenever the camera scanner detects a QR code. After the Application crashes it does not re-open. I have to re-install the Application all over again. I have been through my crash reports and through many tutorials but in vain. iOS version 9.3.1. My crash report is as follows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  1

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
13.169796    CFNetwork                  0x000000002470c97d TCP Conn 0x176ccda0 complete. fd: 8, err: 0
13.170086    CFNetwork                  0x000000002470da7f TCP Conn 0x176ccda0 event 1. err: 0
14.046770    CFNetwork                  0x000000002470dafd TCP Conn 0x176ccda0 started
14.876383    CFNetwork                  0x000000002470c97d TCP Conn 0x176ce850 complete. fd: 4, err: 0
14.876713    CFNetwork                  0x000000002470da7f TCP Conn 0x176ce850 event 1. err: 0
15.895108    CFNetwork                  0x000000002470dafd TCP Conn 0x176ce850 started
15.898309    CFNetwork                  0x000000002475326f Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
15.898309    CFNetwork                  0x000000002475324b Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
15.898309    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247958f7 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x23953a82 objc_msgSend + 2
1   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x0006c2cc +[StringEncryption DecryptString:key:] (StringEncryption.m:65)
2   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00052882 -[BRSyncDataHelper checkBadgeScan:alertTag:] (BRSyncDataHelper.m:153)
3   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00055180 -[BRQRScannerViewController barcodeData:] (BRQRScannerViewController.m:269)
4   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x0005503e -[BRQRScannerViewController captureResult:result:] (BRQRScannerViewController.m:192)
5   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x0008325c ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 9010
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d1bcbe _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d1bcaa _dispatch_client_callout + 22
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d20558 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1532
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2414b7d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x24149cce __CFRunLoopRun + 1590
11  CoreFoundation                  0x24098288 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2409807c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
13  GraphicsServices                0x256b4af8 GSEventRunModal + 160
14  UIKit                           0x287bd2c4 UIApplicationMain + 144
15  BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00017e0a main (main.mm:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x23d44872 start + 2

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e192f8 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d2b836 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 254
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d1d916 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 38

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e18864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebae18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23eba9fc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.utility-qos
Thread 3:
0   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00084762 ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 14392
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d29fe6 _dispatch_apply_invoke + 150
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d276a0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d2707a _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebae0c _pthread_wqthread + 1024
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23eba9fc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e18864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebae18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23eba9fc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e038a8 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e036a8 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2414b72c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x24149ab2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1050
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24098288 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2409807c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6   Foundation                      0x248e557c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268
7   Foundation                      0x24933d6c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
8   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x0006666e +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:158)
9   Foundation                      0x249b662c __NSThread__start__ + 1144
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebcc7e _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebcbf2 _pthread_start + 110
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebaa08 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e038a8 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e036a8 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2414b72c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x24149ab2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1050
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24098288 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2409807c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6   CFNetwork                       0x246edb2e +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486
7   Foundation                      0x249b662c __NSThread__start__ + 1144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebcc7e _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebcbf2 _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebaa08 thread_start + 8

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.utility-qos
Thread 7:
0   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00084770 ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 14406
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d29fe6 _dispatch_apply_invoke + 150
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x23d2a3b6 dispatch_apply_f + 522
3   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00084676 ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 14156
4   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x0008415a ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 12848
5   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x0008419a ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 12912
6   BUZZ Tech Suite                 0x00082daa ZXNotFoundErrorInstance + 7808
7   AVFoundation                    0x29ba9538 -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _handleRemoteQueueOperation:] + 308
8   AVFoundation                    0x29ba93e2 __47-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _updateRemoteQueue:]_block_invoke + 162
9   CoreMedia                       0x2616e7ec __FigRemoteOperationReceiverCreateMessageReceiver_block_invoke + 204
10  CoreMedia                       0x26184412 __FigRemoteQueueReceiverSetHandler_block_invoke2 + 186
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d2e5ba _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 2042
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d1dbfe _dispatch_source_invoke + 738
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d259ec _dispatch_queue_drain + 592
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d1ee16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 282
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d259ec _dispatch_queue_drain + 592
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d1ee16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 282
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d2720c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 400
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x23d2707a _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebae0c _pthread_wqthread + 1024
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23eba9fc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e17eec __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x24150bd0 __CFSocketManager + 572
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebcc7e _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebcbf2 _pthread_start + 110
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebaa08 thread_start + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x23e18864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23ebae18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23eba9fc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000004    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x400106c8
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x40010754
    r8: 0x3b0854b4    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3a306100     r11: 0x3b083e00
    ip: 0x00000176    sp: 0x400106a0      lr: 0x23d2b837      pc: 0x23e192f8
  cpsr: 0x20000010
```

Can anyone help me fix this strange error> Thanks in advance. !

Comment: Can you run the app through the debugger on a real iPad?

Comment: @PhillipMills The crash is in thread 1, not thread 0.

Comment: @rmaddy Yess I can run the app through debugger on a real iPad.

Comment: Does it crash when debugging through Xcode on a real iPad or does it only crash when not using the debugger?

Comment: It does not crashes when using Xcode. The application crashes only in iPad when the Archive .ipa file is installed and run in iPad. !